# Flutter audio record in background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background

Is it possible to record audio in background in flutter, if yes could you provide a code for that, i tried but always give me errors about the permission.
The app need this feature for protection purpose.

Comment: You could use `Isolates` to record the audio in the background,
but do check the ios background limitations. Also, no one would provide you a code here, better to start with what did you try & where did you encounter an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Android it can be achieved using a foreground service which can start your recording in the background. On iOS however you've to write some code to make it record in the background if possible. Following plugins can be used in your project. [flutter_foreground_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_plugin) & [flutter_audio_recorder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_recorder)

Comment: awesome, nice idea